# opengl - transform part of an object

Tags: opengl

So I have a matrix stack for manipulating an object in world space. I can specify general matrix transformations for the entire object, but I don't know how to specify specific transformations for each point in the object, if, I, say, want to manipulate each point with a separate transformation.
How do I manipulate transforms in OpenGL for specific points within an object?

Comment: look into how model animations are commonly done; with bones and weights

Comment: either in GLSL vertex shader (passing matrices in per vertex manner as attributes instead of uniform) or on CPU side you recompute the vertexes before rendering (this might be slow for complicated objects)